# Number of swaps and comparisons in Shaker/Cocktail sort -Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparison, swap, bubble-sort

I have looked at how to count swaps and comparisons for bubble sort and modified a shaker sort program to this:

```
 public void shakerSort(int a[])  // http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cocktail-sort/
{
    boolean swapped = true;
    comparisons = 0;
    swaps = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = a.length;

    while (swapped==true)
    {         
        swapped = false;

        for (int i = start; i < end-1; ++i)
        {
          comparisons++; //count comparisons
          if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
          {
             int temp = a[i];
             a[i] = a[i+1];
             a[i+1] = temp;
             swapped = true;

             swaps++; //count swaps
          }
        }

        if (swapped==false)
        {
            break; 
        }

        swapped = false;

        end = end-1;

        for (int i = end-1; i >=start; i--)
        {
          comparisons++; //count comparisons
            if (a[i] > a[i+1])
            {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
                swaps++; //count swaps
            }
        }

        start = start+1;

    }

}
```

However, for an array of 100 elements where the number of comparisons should always be 4950 ( n(n-1)/2 ), it gives me a value that changes every time I run the program- and this value is always less than 4950.

Why does it do this, and how can I fix it?

(NOTE: The array is randomized each time the program is run)

Also, is the swap count okay?

Comment: Do you give same array as input.?

Comment: It's always the same size but it is randomized differently each time.  Would that affect it?

Comment: yes, There can be a case.! see, You gave a loop, `while(swap)` now, It MUST be the reason to the variation in count. think if there are no variables swapped and your `swap` did not change to `true`. hence it is `false`. so in that case, the program will not go in loop. That is the only reason for different counts. I am not sure about the sorting logic. but that loop is making all changes for sure.

Comment: Hmm, I see, but I'm not sure how to fix it then...

Comment: Nothing is to fix. Everything is right. I check the algorithm. and your code is perfect. You just have to accept that the number of iterations will be different for every input. so the count is going to be different. Also `swap` count is also perfect.!

Comment: Oh, then that's wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160368/discussion-between-jay-joshi-and-thedeadline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take example and understand changes in count:

> array[5] = { 2 , 1 , 3 , 4 , 5 }

**How many iterations should it take.?**

first, shaker sort will check from start and then from last in every iterations. `count` is 0 at start.

```
 2 , 1 , 3 , 4 , 5 --> count = 1
 ^   ^
 it will swap 2 and 1
 swap count++

 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5  --> count = 2
             ^   ^
 no swap
```

the program will again check because the `swap = true`

```
 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 --> count = 3
     ^   ^
  no swap

 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5  --> count = 4
         ^   ^
 no swap
```

the program will end because now `swap = false`.

---

Now lets take different array:

> array[5] = { 5 , 4 , 3 , 2 , 1 }

for the same, Iterations will be much more that 4 iterations.!

---

Hence, For same size array and different value, number of iterations will be different.!

Note: swap count and iteration count is used perfect in the the program :)

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped out a lot! :DD